# Avoid " (quotation) when viewing Adobe Acrobat using Hyperref

Tags: hyperref

I have created PDF files using `hyperref` package. When viewing the PDF file in `Adobe Acrobat` pressed `Ctrl+D` all the Author fields is showing with `"`. How to avoid this using `LaTeX`?

I have created the PDF file `LaTeX filename.tex`, `dvips filename.dvi`, `ps2pdf filename.ps`.

I know about `pdflatex` command. But i want the solutions using `latex`.

My minimal file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
pdftitle={Testing PDF Metadatas},
pdfsubject={Article Subject},
pdfauthor={Junji\'{e} Shen, Balaji Wang, Shñ J.},
pdfkeywords={Article Keywords}
}
\begin{document}
\title{Testing PDF Metadatas}
\author{Junji\'{e} Shen, Balaji Wang, Shñ J.}
\today
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

But when i was tested using `exiftool` it's not showing `"` marks in `metadata`. or need to use any other `LaTeX` Packages?

Comment: I assume that these are three authors? The PDF reference doesn't really have a good idea how to handle multiple authors in the info dictionary and what happens here is up to the PDF viewer. If you would add xmp-metadata (with a current (!) LaTeX you could do that with `\DocumentMetadata{}` before `\documentclass`), then adobe reader would remove the quotes and separate with semicolon.  BTW: in the \author command you should normally separate authors with \and and not with a comma.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for your immediate action could you please provide some example using of `\DocumentMetadata{}` or any links?

Comment: see the documentation of pdfmanagement-testphase.  Or search the site.  You can also try hyperxmp instead.